# How to centralize text on a div block that remains centralized through out the transition when transforming (HTML, CSS)?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have this `div` block which has a "Hello" on top of it. The block is designed in such a way that when you hover over it, it transforms and rotates 360 degrees (i.e. back to its original state but a bit bigger). I want the "Hello" to be on the center of the block throughout the transition and transformation period. I centralized it using:

```css
position: relative;  
top: 40px;  
transition: .4s;
```

on the `p` in CSS but when the div is transformed, the text ends up being on top of the block i.e. not centralized. How do I make it happen?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(147, 141, 223);
  transition: width .6s, height .6s, transform .6s;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

div:hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
p {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  transition: .6s;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <b><p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; color: white">Hello</p></b>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GTIPO2S358AV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using two independently styled elements, so that when you rotate the div, you should also adjust the p in the div, using a `div:hover p` selector, to change the p's top.

A more straightforward solution would be to dispense with styling the p altogether, and put all the necessary styles in the `div` and `div:hover` selectors.
I would go with a `line-height` rather than changing the position, though.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(147, 141, 223);
  transition: width .6s, height .6s, transform .6s;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height:100px;      /* new: line height the same as the height */
}

div:hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  line-height:300px;      /* same */
}
p {
  transition: .6s;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <b><p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; color: white">Hello</p></b>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `top` property of `p` to center it, and you aren't changing it on transition.

You can add a `div:hover p` tag where you adjust the `top` property, but a simpler solution is to use flexbox to allow the browser to center the `p` dynamically; you only have to write it within one tag and you don't have to calculate the pixels yourself.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(147, 141, 223);
  transition: width .6s, height .6s, transform .6s;
  /* removing this:
  text-align: center;
  */
  position: relative;
  /* Adding flexbox properties to center a single 
     element within the current one: */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div:hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

p {
  /* Removing this:
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  */
  transition: .6s;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <b><p style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; color: white">Hello</p></b>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```